# Djangosaml2 the use of metadata

Tags: python, django, azure, saml, adfs2.0

I'm manage to integrate SAML authentication in my Django application using the package [Djangosaml2](https://djangosaml2.readthedocs.io/) and [Pysaml2](https://github.com/IdentityPython/pysaml2) with Azure as IdP provider.

everything is working properly I can login with SAML and log out.

What I don't understand is what is the use of having a metadata at the url https://panda.company.com/saml/metadata and what is the use of having a url https://panda.company.com/saml2/ls/ ?
Because with just the remote_metadata.xml provided by Azure is enough to login and logout.

```
SAML_CONFIG = {
    'xmlsec_binary': '/usr/bin/xmlsec1',
    'name': 'CloudBolt SP',
    'entityid': 'https://panda.company.com/',
    'service': {
        'sp': {
            'want_assertions_signed': False,
            'want_response_signed': False,
            'allow_unsolicited': True,
            'endpoints': {
                'assertion_consumer_service': [
                        ('https://panda.company.com/saml2/acs/', saml2.BINDING_HTTP_POST),
                    ],
                'single_logout_service': [
                        ('https://panda.company.com/saml2/ls/', saml2.BINDING_HTTP_REDIRECT),
                ],
            },
            'required_attributes': ['email'],
        },
    },
    'debug': 1,
    'key_file': os.path.join(SAML2_DIR, 'saml.key'),  # private part
    'cert_file': os.path.join(SAML2_DIR, 'saml.crt'),  # public part
    'allow_unknown_attributes': True,
    'attribute_map_dir': os.path.join(/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/saml2/attributemaps'),
    'metadata': {
        'local': [os.path.join(SAML2_DIR, 'remote_metadata.xml')],
    },
    'contact_person': [{
        'given_name': 'First',
        'sur_name': 'Last',
        'company': 'Company',
        'email_address': 'me@company.com',
        'contact_type': 'technical'
    }],
    'organization': {
        'name': 'Company',
        'display_name': 'Company',
        'url': 'http://www.company.com',
    },
    'valid_for': 24,  # how long is our metadata valid
    'accepted_time_diff': 120, #seconds
}

SAML_DJANGO_USER_MAIN_ATTRIBUTE = 'username'
SAML_CREATE_UNKNOWN_USER = True
SAML_ATTRIBUTE_MAPPING = {
        'email': ('email', ),
        'givenName': ('first_name', ),
        'sn': ('last_name', ),
        'uid': ('username', ),
}
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_metadata provides some insights. It's mostly for the purpose of maintaining the configuration.

Comment: @KamilWozniak thx for the link. I understand the utility of the metadata but my idP provider already given me one. I just don't understand why I should also buid a metadata a give it to my idP. In the doc of Djangosaml2 it's says `Now you need to send the entity id and the metadata of this new SP to the IdP administrators so they can add it to their list of trusted services.`

Comment: From my experience @panda42 the metadata under the `/saml/metadata` endpoint is prepared automatically by your service from the configuration. In case anything changes, this endpoint will have the latest data there.

Comment: @Lolm_47 Can you provide me some links or references to integrate SAML metadata with django project for SSO ...I have used many packages,but nothing worked for me...Any leads would be appreciated